# How to get the original count after joining tables?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the number of products / number of systems for each store. The tables look like this:

```
Store
Id
100
200

Customer
Id      |    dealerId
1       |    100
2       |    200

System
Id  | CustomerId
20  | 2
30  | 2
40  | 2
50  | 1

Product
Id  |  SystemId
1000 | 20
2000 | 50
```

I am trying to get :

```
storeId  |  Number of systems  | number of products   |    average
100      |            1        |           1          |       1/1
200      |            3        |           1          |       1/3
```

I have written  this query. I get the right number of products but the number of systems is messed up because I am joining the tables. Is there a way I can get the total number of systems for each store?

```
SELECT
  s.Id as Store, 
  COUNT(Distinct SystemsIden) as NumOfSystems,
  COUNT(distinct ProductIden) as NumOfProduct,
  CAST(COUNT(distinct ProductIden)as float)/CAST(COUNT(Distinct SystemsIden) as 
  float) as average
FROM 
 Store s
  INNER JOIN
  (
  Select systemsiden,CustomerIden,ProductIden, Customer.StoreId as 
  storeiden from
 (
  select Product.ID as ProductIden, System.Id as systemsiden, System.customerId   as CustomerIden from product join Ssystem On System.Id = Product.SystemIdId
)
  table1 join Customer
  on Customer.Id = CustomerIden
)
  table2 On s.Id = storeiden
GROUP BY
  s.Id
```

Comment: Why are you casting your count to floats? You should use decimals. Floats are approximate datatypes.

Comment: @Dan chances are you are using either one of mysql or sql-server. Please remove the other tag from your question as it serves no real purpose, unless your code really has to run on both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for extensive subquery usage, simple outer joins will suffice:

```
SELECT  st.Id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT sy.Id) AS SystemCount,
        COUNT(DISTINCT pr.Id) AS ProductCount,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT sy.Id) = 0 THEN 0
             ELSE 1.0 * COUNT(DISTINCT pr.Id) / COUNT(DISTINCT sy.Id)
        END AS Average
FROM    Store AS st
LEFT JOIN Customer AS cu ON cu.DealerId = st.Id
LEFT JOIN System AS sy ON sy.CustomerId = cu.Id
LEFT JOIN Product AS pr ON pr.SystemId = sy.Id
GROUP BY st.Id;
```

[image: query results]

Comment: I get an error :Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Divide by zero error encountered.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: It works given your example data. Updated to use `ISNULL`.

Comment: Added explicit check for divide by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  s.Id as Store, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT sys.id) as NumOfSystems,
  COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) as NumOfProduct,
  IFNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT p.id),0)/IFNULL(COUNT(Distinct sys.id),1) as average
FROM Store s
INNER JOIN Customer c
ON c.dealerId = s.id
INNER JOIN System sys
ON sys.customerId = c.id
INNER JOIN product p
ON sys.id=p.systemId
GROUP BY s.Id
```